# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.cj.MysqlType>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to connect to a mysql server from android studio. I have added the mysql connectors jar-file to the project and to the classpath environment variables. Everything compiles fine but at runtime I get the following error:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.cj.MysqlType>: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/SQLType;
```

This is the code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql2.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql2303751",user,pass);
```

The runtime error happens in the `con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)` line so the driver is set properly which indicates the jar-file has been properly added to the project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hope this helps

This is my url

```
// change the url and try to add http or https before the url
String url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3306/myDatabase";

//my codes to connect
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                Class.forName(classs);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url , username, password);
```